# Lollipop .setPackage("com.android.phone")

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I use setPackage("com.android.phone") to explicitly tell Android to use the default dialer. This works well up to 4.4.4.

After upgrading to Lollipop, this fails.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[CallIntentService]
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x14000000 pkg=com.android.phone }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1765)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1237)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1219)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:322)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Do we already have a workaround for this?

Comment: never hard code a package name because it can always change and be different on other devices as is probably the case here

Comment: True. Wonder what the constants name is, though.

Comment: why do you specifically want the android dialer, the user should choose what dialer they want to use

Comment: That's politics. The App I am working on is not ought to be used by general populous, it's an company internal thing.

Comment: Find the package name of the dialer on lollipop, then. Use it conditionally. Check whether it exists before using it, and revert to intent-chooser if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name of Lollipop's dialer is `com.google.android.dialer` (on Nexus devices at least).

If you really want to hardcode the package name, you may have to detect which dialer is available on the device.

Comment: Luckily, I have a limited set of device types. I wonder what other option I have besides hardcoding it.

Answer (score 1):

```
setPackage name has changed for Lollipop and above.

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);  
intent.setPackage("com.android.phone");        < 5 (Lollipop)
intent.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom");    >= 5 (Lollipop)
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:12121212"));
startActivity(intent);

But its better to choose user.
works "com.android.server.telecom" 5 and above.
```